# Load a pivoted CSV file to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, bash, ubuntu-18.04, unpivot

I have a csv file with identifying and date information and then a several dozen data columns (sample below).

[image]

In the spirit of relational DBs (and also to avoid creating a table with 100+ columns), it seems preferable to load the dataset *after* I've pivoted the data such that column names for the data columns are subsequently included as row entries instead (sample below; data values aren't consistent with first table, including to demonstrate desired layout):
[image]

Occurs to me I could load the data to a place-holder table in MySQL, pivot within MySQL and insert into a new table but wonder if there's a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with MySQL, loading the data to an intermediate table, then unpivoting it into the target table seems like the relevant strategy.

To load the file in the table database, you can use the `LOAD DATA INTO FILE` syntax.

Then, you can unpivot with `union all`:

```
insert into targettable (
    ticker, dimension, item, calendardate, datekey, reportperiod, astupdated, value
)
select ticker, dimension, 'accoci', calendardate, datekey, reportperiod, astupdated, accoci
from mytable
union all
select ticker, dimension, 'assets', calendardate, datekey, reportperiod, astupdated, assets
from mytable
union all 
select ticker, dimension, 'assetsavg', calendardate, datekey, reportperiod, astupdated, assetsavg
from mytable
...
```

Disclaimer: I am not convinced that unpivoting this dataset will eventually make things better or easier. That would ultimately depend on how you want to consume it, which you did not tell.

Comment: suppose I sort of took it for granted given the nature of RDBMS.  I don't imagine I'll need to join to 'item' at all; would mostly just be using the item name as part of a filter, with joins on ticker/date.